# MOSFET question

Tags: mosfet

Will it damage an [IRF740 MOSFET](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91054/91054.pdf) to have a positive 108 V potential connected to it's drain before a conductive signal is connected to it's gate?

Comment: By 'positive 108 potential' do you mean 108 volts? The maximum Drain-Source Voltage is 400 V, according to the datasheet.

Comment: What do you mean by "apply a conductive signal"? Are you asking about what happens if the gate is floating?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean that the gate is left open, then yes the part could be damaged.

When the gate is left floating it can get a high enough \$V_{\text{gs}}\$ to turn on.  If the source of \$V_{\text{ds}}\$ has sufficient current the FET could be damaged.  Some FETs have a ratio of \$C_{\text{gs}}\$ to \$C_{\text{dg}}\$ that applying a voltage to the drain with open gate will turn on the FET.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, no, if you are not violating the datasheet spec of 400V then you will be fine.

The long answer is still no, but the reason are interesting.  If you understand how MOSFET's are made you realize that the EOS (electrical over stress) on the gate is perhaps it's most sensitive aspect.  Since the Source and Drain are close to the channel which is controlled by the gate, it only makes sense that if the gate voltage is too high/low with respect to the Source or Drain then the magnitude of the Gate/channel electric field will be too high and that causes the Gate oxide to rupture.

The reason this device can handle the higher voltage on the Drain is that it is a MOSFET variant called a DMOS transistor - Double Diffused MOS or perhaps Diffused MOS (depends upon the company).  It really menas is that the drain structure has been engineered to prevent high Drain/Gate electric fields to prevent the EOS.

So in use, you can have a very high S/D voltage and the Gate Oxide will be fine as long as you don't take the Gate farther away from the Source than +/- 20 V.  If you decide foolishly that this is a symmetrical device you will kill it.

You should not allow the gate to float to arbitrary voltages such that it gets out that +/- 20V range.